# Hibernate inheritance table per class and single table mix

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance, table-per-subclass

I am developing online web shop, and I need help with Hibernate mapping. I have the following inheritance:

```
         BaseProduct
         /         \
     Guitar         Drum
     /    \         /    \
AcGuitar   ElGuitar AcDrum ElectricDrum
```

What I want:
 
1)Common fields such as id, name, description will be in @MappedSuperclass BaseProduct. 
2)Musical instrument **types** (Guitar, Drum) will have common fields for these types of instruments.
3)At the end, concrete classes AvGuitar, ElGuitar etc will have unique properties for this concrete instruments.

The most problem is that I want that there will be two tables for two **types** of instruments: t_guitar and t_drum (InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS), and for concrete classes one table InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE, which means there will be one table for acoustic and electric guitar and one table for acoustic and electric drums with corresponding discriminant column.

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

**Update 1**

As I need to interact with the whole hierarchy as one general type and map products to another entities, I did the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseProduct { //supercclass 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    // etc
}
```

And medium class Product:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Product extends BaseProduct {
}
```

So, with this solutions any mixes unfortunately still don't work.

Comment: Upping this question. I'm currently looking into a solution for the same problem. Seems that Hibernate is silently ignoring SINGLE_TABLE annotation and looks for tables (in your case) named AC_GUITAR, EL_GUITAR, AC_DRUM or ELECTRIC_DRUM.

Ever managed to arrive to a conclusion? (why it isn't possible is also a good help)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like...

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class base { 
    @Id
    private  String id;   //yr field

    }


    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="classname",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
    )
    public class drum  extends base{

   String drumProperties;  //yr drum prop.

    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="classname",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
    )
    public class guitar extends base {

    private String guitarProperties;    //guitar prop.
    }


    @Entity
    public class AcGuitar extends guitar{
    String acGuitarprop;

    }

   @Entity
   public class ElGuitar extends guitar{
   String elGuitarprop;

   }

    @Entity
   public class ElDrum extends drum{
   String elDrumprop;

   }

    @Entity

    public class AcDrum extends drum{
   String acDrumprop;

     }
```

on result u ll get two table in yr DB ,i. e. guitar and drum

Comment: Prateek Singh, thanks a lot for your help, but your solution doesn't allow me to map products to another entities. I want to have single base class (BaseProduct), and map it, for example, to User entity etc.

Comment: @vmolchanov this solution achieves exactly what you described in your question. if you have some more requirements then add them to the question. also I have no idea what you mean by "map products to other entities": please provide an example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class base { 
@Id
private  String id;   //yr field

}
```

now there ll be three table in yr db .for your reference check out. [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-subclass-annotation-xml-mapping/)